# Syntax error when storing Pig output

Tags: apache-pig

I am having some issues with storing my pig output to a file.  This is what I am using to store:

> 'STORE rel INTO 'simple'; '

If I Dump 'rel' I get:

```
>(car,0.5,(door,tire,jello,truck,random))
(toy,0.5,(jeep,bunny toy))
(door,0.5,(car,jello,random))
>(jeep,0.5,(toy,bunny toy))
```

What I get in the file is:

```
<Yulias-MacBook-Pro:~ yuliatolskaya$ /Users/yuliatolskaya/Documents/misc/pig_clustering/simple/part-r-00000 ; exit;
/Users/yuliatolskaya/Documents/misc/pig_clustering/simple/part-r-00000: line 1: syntax  error near unexpected token `('
/Users/yuliatolskaya/Documents/misc/pig_clustering/simple/part-r-00000: line 1: `car    0.5 (door,tire,jello,truck,random)'
logout
[Process completed] >
```

I am really not sure what the problem is, as there are no errors in the logfiles...Please Help!

Comment: This actually turned out to be a very silly person, but I am going to share just in case someone has the same issue. The problem was that when I was just double clicking it was not opening this file as a text file, however if I right clicked and selected "open with TextMate" the file opened and was perfectly right. A silly issue for sure, but it took me a while to realize what was going on.